# Importing header twice: duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

> duplicate symbol _webViewManager in:
>       app/Build/Intermediates/app-name.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app-name.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PostsShowViewController.o
>       app/Build/Intermediates/app-name.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app-name.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirstViewController.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am getting the above error when I am trying to compile.
This happens when I try to import a file called `WebViewManager.h` in two different View Controllers.

*WebViewManager.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewManager : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;

+ (id)getUniqueWebViewManager: (UIViewController *)container;
- (void)loadUrlWithString: (NSString *)urlString;
- (void) removeWebViewFromContainer;

@end
```

*FirstViewController.m*

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "PostsShowViewController.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "WebViewManager.h"
```

*PostsShowController.m*

```
#import "PostsShowViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "WebViewManager.h"
```

Similarly, the same error occurs if I try to `#import "Constants.h"` in multiple places.

Edit:

*Constants.h*

```
NSString *BASE_URL = @"google.com";
```

**Edit2:**

Occurences WebViewManager:

**FirstViewController.m**

```
@implementation FirstViewController

WebViewManager *webViewManager;
```

Comment: Have you declared the same class twice ? Or a class with the same name already exists in some external dependency ? Sometimes it happens if you define stuff in the header file and not in .m file.

Comment: @SamhanSalahuddin hm.. I am not entirely sure. The same error happens when I try to import a header file that only has one line: `NSSTring *BASE_URL = @"google.com";` in two different view controllers.

Comment: Please show all occurrences of `webViewManager` in your project (note: case is important).

Comment: Let's say there are two FirstViewController and SecondViewController. If I include `#import Constants.h` in FirstViewController, it compiles fine. If I include the import statement inside SecondViewController too, it doesn't compile. `Constants.h` has only one string: `NSString *BASE_URL = @"http://google.com";` Do you think you have an idea?

Comment: @MaximusS I answered that one already.

Comment: Sorry, I must've missed the answer. Could you maybe post your answer again?

Comment: I don't have enough information for a complete answer.  My answer applies to `BASE_URL`, however I made the assumption that `webViewManager` follows the same pattern.  Please provide the information I asked for above.

Comment: @trojanfoe sure! I just updated my answer with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to use `extern` in the header file, therefore every implementation file that includes `Constants.h` is declaring its own instance of `BASE_URL`.

You want:

```
extern NSString *BASE_URL
```

and this in `Constants.m`:

```
NSString *BASE_URL = @"google.com";
```

Alternatively, you could also just use this in `Constants.h`:

```
#define BASE_URL @"google.com"
```

and forget about `Constants.m`.

<strike>However I don't have enough information to tell you why the linker is complaining about `webViewManager`.</strike>

OK, Part #2:

The issue is that there are multiple global symbols called `webViewManager` as you are mis-declaring them.  Use:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    WebViewManager *_webViewManager;
}
```

(and the same for the other class).  This makes them *instance variables*, not global variables.

Comment: `Constants.h` is just a file that contains one string `BASE_URL`. I included it in the question to say even without `WebViewManager` files, if I try to include a simple header file `Constants.h` in multiple view controllers, I get an error.